# Relation between Node.js and FireFox

Tags: node.js, firefox

I knew that node.js based on V8 Javascript engine of Google Chrome.
And I want to know If Node.js  can run on FireFox ,then how?

What version of firefox support V8 javascript Engine or Node.js?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are mixing up JS Engine and browser.

- V8 is the JS Engine of Google Chrome (also used by Chromium, MongoDB among others).
- SpiderMonkey is the JS Engine of Firefox (also used by GNOME and Adobe as examples).
- Chakra is Microsoft's JS Engine, by Internet Explorer, old Edge (new one is Chromium based, and as such use V8) and some other Microsoft projects.

Node.js is based on V8, which you confuse with Google Chrome. They use the same JS Engine, but you don't need any part of Chrome itself to use Node.js.

There has been project to port node.js to SpiderMonkey, like [SpiderNode](https://github.com/mozilla/spidernode) or [JXcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore), but aren't actively developed anymore.

On the other side, Microsoft had worked on making [node-chakracore](https://github.com/nodejs/node-chakracore). It has been archived at the end of 2019. It even had some really interesting options on it (Reverse Time Travel for example).

Comment: thanks but I have one question yet. Wikipedia says "The V8 JavaScript Engine is an open source JavaScript engine developed by The Chromium Project for the Google Chrome web browser". And I want to know how come FireFox support V8 engine. Then when they implemented that function on firefox?

Comment: Ah, node.js use V8, and a fork of it use SpiderMonkey, but Firefox only use SpiderMonkey, not V8.

Comment: Ok!                Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can close the question by clicking on the green mark next to the answer you think is best. It also award you reputation points.

Comment: https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/firefox-dev/2018-August/006716.html